# Comparing a dataframe on string lengths for different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, min, string-length

I am trying to get the string lengths for different columns. Seems quite straightforward with:

```
df['a'].str.len()
```

But I need to apply it to multiple columns. And then get the minimum on it.

Something like:

```
df[['a','b','c']].str.len().min
```

I know the above doesn't work, but hopefully you get the idea. Column `a`, `b`, `c` all contain names and I want to retrieve the shortest name.

Also because of huge data, I am avoiding creating other columns to save on size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need list comprehension, because `string` function works only with `Series` (`column`):

```
print ([df[col].str.len().min() for col in ['a','b','c']])
```

Another solution with `apply`:

```
print ([df[col].apply(len).min() for col in ['a','b','c']])
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['h','gg','yyy'],
                   'b':['st','dsws','sw'],
                   'c':['fffff','','rr'],
                   'd':[1,3,5]})

print (df)

     a     b      c  d
0    h    st  fffff  1
1   gg  dsws         3
2  yyy    sw     rr  5

print ([df[col].str.len().min() for col in ['a','b','c']])
[1, 2, 0]
```

**Timings**:

```
#[3000 rows x 4 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [17]: %timeit ([df[col].apply(len).min() for col in ['a','b','c']])
100 loops, best of 3: 2.63 ms per loop

In [18]: %timeit ([df[col].str.len().min() for col in ['a','b','c']])
The slowest run took 4.12 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100 loops, best of 3: 2.88 ms per loop
```

**Conclusion**:

`apply` is faster, but not works with `None`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['h','gg','yyy'],
                   'b':[None,'dsws','sw'],
                   'c':['fffff','','rr'],
                   'd':[1,3,5]})


print (df)
     a     b      c  d
0    h  None  fffff  1
1   gg  dsws         3
2  yyy    sw     rr  5

print ([df[col].apply(len).min() for col in ['a','b','c']])
```

> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

```
print ([df[col].str.len().min() for col in ['a','b','c']])
[1, 2.0, 0]
```

EDIT by comment:

```
#fail with None
print (df[['a','b','c']].applymap(len).min(axis=1))
0    1
1    0
2    2
dtype: int64
```

---

```
#working with None
print (df[['a','b','c']].apply(lambda x: x.str.len().min(), axis=1))
0    1
1    0
2    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hey @jezrael, looks good. Let me give it a try when I'm back.

Comment: Thanks for the sample. What I am trying to achieve is at a row basis though. Meaning, for a, b, c the answer on another column lets say will be 1,0,2

Comment: Are there `None` values?

Comment: Not at this point. I basically drop na for all the columns I am using. But maybe in the future.

Comment: Ok, I add solution with None also.

Comment: Hey@jezreal, will it be possible to then based on the function, [1,0,2], use it to get the substring of each of the column? so a,b and c, then a1,b1,and c1. For example. the first row will show, [h, None, f].

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you. I think the best is create new question with samples and desired output.